# Finding the transition matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Folk wisdom holds that in Itaca it rains with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ every day of the year. However, if we know that a specific day is rainy, then the following day is rainy with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Suppose that Itaca weather is a Markov chain (with states "rainy" and "sunny"). What is its transition matrix?

So surely we have, where $X_n$ is the state of the weather at time $n$, $$P(X_{n+1} = rain | X_n = rain) = \frac{1}{2}$$ And further, that $$P(X_{n+1} = sunny | X_n = rain) = \frac{1}{2}$$ However, I'm unsure how to interpret this 1/3 probability - is this equivalent to $$P(X_{n+1} = rain | X_n = sunny) = \frac{1}{3}$$ or am I making some mistake? It just seems that this is too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition matrix looks like this:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
x & 1-x\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The first state is that it's rainy, and the second is that it's sunny.  The long-run distribution of states satisfies: 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1/3 & 2/3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
x & 1-x\\
\end{array}
\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1/3 & 2/3 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
So $x=1/4$, and $1-x=3/4$.

Comment: Ah, with $
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1/3 & 2/3 \\
\end{array}
\right]$ being the stationary distribution?

Comment: Indeed.  You can think of it as the stationary distribution or the long-run frequency of states.  Now you're cooking!

Comment: That's extremely intuitive - thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I used to be an assistant professor at Cornell.  I miss Ithaca in summer.  :)

Comment: That's impressive! I don't mind Madison's summers either!